# Width of image output by imresize is inconsistent in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-resizing

I am trying to resize an image according to another image size in MATLAB and it seemed to be an easy task. But I am getting some unexpected output. Here is the code

```matlab
msg = imread(msgImgPath);
[msgH, msgW] = size(msg);
fprintf('Height = %d and width = %d', msgH, msgW)

rszMsg = imresize(msg, [720 1280]);
[rszMsgH, rszMsgW] = size(rszMsg);
```

In the case of the image I have used, `msgH = 1280`, `msgW = 5760`. Now `rszMsgH = 720` which is as expected but `rszMsgW = 3840` which should be `1280`. Can you say why is this happening?

I am using MATLAB R2021a.

Comment: Your image likely has 3 channels. `1280 x 3 = 3840` Try `[rszMsgH, rszMsgW, rszMsgC] = size(rszMsg);`

Comment: Thanks, @beaker. That solves the problem.